# Javascript script to change the source of an image

Tags: php, javascript, json, flexigrid

I am using flexigrid for one of my projects and I need to come up with a way to change the image source depending on the value of one of the cells. For people who are used to flexigrid, I have the following code:

```
$json .= ",'".addslashes("<span><img src='' id='flag' />" . $row['availability']. "</span>")."'";
```

and my javascript that I've come up with , looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var available = "<?php echo '$row[availability]' ?>"; 

if (available == 0) { 
document.getElementById('flag').src="images/flag_red.png"; 
} 
elseif (available == 1) { 
document.getElementById('flag').src="images/flag_green.png"; 
} 
else { 
document.getElementById('flag').src="images/flag_orange.png"; 
}
```

I am not sure where I need to insert this function and how to trigger it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Cristian.

LE: The code where the problem is being reported:

```
url: 'post2.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            colModel : [
                {display: 'ID', name : 'id', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'center', hide: true},
                {display: 'URL', name : 'url', width : 450, sortable : false, align: 'left'},
                {display: 'File Name', name : 'filename', width : 270, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                {display: 'Availability', name : 'availability', width : 50, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                {display: 'State', name : 'state', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                {display: 'Total Size', name : 'totalsize', width : 90, sortable : false, align: 'center'},
                {display: 'Current Size', name : 'currentsize', width : 90, sortable : false, align: 'center'},
                {display: 'Procent', name : 'procent', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                {display: 'Log',  width : 20, sortable : false, align: 'center'},
                ],
            buttons : [
                {name: 'Add', bclass: 'add', onpress : test},
                {separator: true},
                {name: 'Delete', bclass: 'delete', onpress : test},
                {separator: true},
                {name: 'Select All', bclass : 'selectall', onpress : test},
                {name: 'DeSelect All', bclass : 'deselectall', onpress : test},
                {separator: true}
                ],
            searchitems : [
                {display: 'URL', name : 'url'},
                {display: 'Filename', name : 'filename', isdefault: true}
                ],
            sortname: "state",
            sortorder: "asc",
            usepager: true,
            title: '',
            useRp: false,
            rp: 5,
            showTableToggleBtn: true,
            } ----- **IE says there is a problem here**         );   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use javascript for this, you can do it directly in your existing PHP line.

```
$json .= ",'" . 
         addslashes("<span><img src='" . 
         ($row['availability'] == 0 ? "images/flag_red.png" :
            ($row['availability'] == 1 ? "images/flag_green.png" : 
               "images/flag_orange.png")
         ) . 
         "' id='flag' />" . $row['availability'] . "</span>") . "'";
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks, Fosco ... greatly appreciated. Everyday I learn a new thing, I am loving it. Cheers, C.

Comment: Tested the code in an older browser IE 7.0.53 and is not working, is causing an error in the javascript, Expected identifier, string or number flexigrid, line 63 character 4, the location pointed out is where the configuration of the table is closing. If I remove the code, no problems.

Comment: @Chris19 I guess that's a separate issue.. is flexigrid compatible with that version of IE?.  As you know this solution didn't involve javascript.

Comment: From what I can tell, the entire table content is generated by javascript, so I am guessing the code disrupts the order in that table. I will update the question in one sec.

Comment: and the code provided by you gets inserted in the post2.php file.

Comment: @Chris19 There's a comma before that `}` which needs to be removed.

Comment: You were right. Thanks, that was the problem. I wonder why was it causing problems only after I added the new code. ??!?!